# Manipulating pandas dataframe using 3 columns of data

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble coming up with a way to accomplish my task. I've got a dataframe with 3 columns: `length, reachcode, and year`.

My example dataframe:

```
year  reachcode  length
1988  1000       1.2
1988  1000       2.0
1990  1000       0.3
1993  1000       0.5
```

I'm trying to find the 'reachcode' duplicates within a single year and then sum 'length' for that year.

After that I would like to compare the summed 'length' values against the same 'reachcode' for different years and keep the smallest value.

So in the example dataframe, the length 1.2 and 2.0 would be summed for the year 1998 and `reachcode = 1000`, and then that value (3.2) would be compared to 1990 and 1993, with the value 0.3 and reachcode retained in a new list.

I have some experience with Pandas, but this is a more complicated task than I've previously had to deal with. My real dataframe is about 40,000 rows, so finding an automated way to do this would be extremely helpful. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a double-stage `groupby`. Firstly groupby `year` and `reachcode` and calculate the sum, reset index so that you can groupby `reachcode` further to take the min of `length`:

```
df.groupby(['year', 'reachcode']).sum().reset_index().groupby('reachcode')['length'].min()

# reachcode
#      1000    0.3
# Name: length, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've used groupby a lot recently, but never realized I could do it in a double-stage like you showed me. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Simply run `groupby` aggregates:

```
df['lengthsum'] = df.groupby(['year', 'reachcode'])['length'].transform(sum)

df['lengthmin'] = df.groupby(['reachcode'])['lengthsum'].transform(min)

#    year  reachcode  length  lengthsum  lengthmin
# 0  1988       1000     1.2        3.2        0.3
# 1  1988       1000     2.0        3.2        0.3
# 2  1990       1000     0.3        0.3        0.3
# 3  1993       1000     0.5        0.5        0.3
```

Comment: That's great. The transform function is super useful. Thanks